# Find out, how a library is linked to a binary via another linked library

Tags: linux, libraries, shared-libraries

Let's say I have a binary `test` and it uses shared libraries

```
a.so
b.so
c.so
```

I have trouble running the binary, because one of the linked libraries links another library `d.so` that seams to be the culprit. However I don't know which library is the one that links it, since in reality there's like 20 libraries instead of 3 and it's very time consuming to go through all of them. `ldd` only gives you the list of libraries that the binary links directly.

On top of that, it seams that there's not one level of indirection, but several. In other words, it seams that there's something like `a.so -> x.so -> blabla.so -> d.so`.

Is there some smart way how to visualize the whole diagram of dependencies or how to find the exact dependency chain that leads to library `d.so`?

In other words, what I want is something like this:

```
a.so -> something.so
     -> second.so
     -> third.so
b.so -> x.so -> blabla.so -> d.so
             -> stuff.so
c.so -> something.else -> yetanotherlib.so
```

or a simplified version where I'd say I want to find, how `d.so` is linked to the binary and it'd spit out

```
a.so -> x.so -> blabla.so -> d.so
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `ldd -v` - this will verbosly indicate the dependency chains.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm doing it on Alpine Linux, which means it's using musl. Based on it's manual it actually seams that `ldd` lists all the dependencies from the whole tree. However the library that I'm looking for isn't in the list but when I run the binary, it throws an error in that library (symbol not found). How is that even possible?

Comment: If the program in question uses `dlopen()` to try and open a library not present in the binarie's linking table, you will get this behaviour.

Comment: ok I read some more about dynamic linking and realized I was thinking about it all wrong. I was only aware of `ldd` and thought that's the only way how shared libs are linked. I wasn't aware of `dlopen`. I found `dlopen` being used in the source code of the binary I'm building and it all makes sense now. Thanks!